# Can the same diaphragm pump be used to pressurize a container?

Tags: pumps

If the output of a diaphragm pump is impeded in any way, or meant to be at higher pressure than the input of the diaphragm pump, will it work, or will it stall out and fail to pump?

In addition to this, are there reversible diaphragm pumps?

Comment: Depends on the pump, I know that some diaphragm pumps are capable of causing sufficient depression to cause the tank to grt crushed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a diaphragm pump is able to pump against a pressure gradient. Typically, positive displacement pumps are able to generate a higher pressure difference, but at a lower flow rate than other technologies, such as centrifugal pumps.

There are not reversible diaphragm pumps, since they rely on one-way-valves for their intrinsic operation.

Comment: One could be designed that uses the other side of the diaphragm....

Comment: ^this is true, I suppose, but access to the rear of the diaphragm is usually difficult, and I have never seen this in practice, so I don’t think my answer is misleading? Such a device would require additional switching / valves to select the direction, and this could be more simply achieved outside the pump. There is no diaphragm pump where changing the direction of the motor would reverse the direction of flow.

Comment: Misleading? Did I suggest that? All I suggested was making use of the other side and, thinking of the petrol pumps I worked on it could be achievable...

Comment: @JonathanRSwift You could achieve this with two three way valves? That's a helluva a lot cheaper than most other solutions.

Comment: Agreed - but the pump itself is still non-reversible. How to use a unidirectional pump to push liquid in two directions is a whole other question!